# question about SQLAlchemy's choice of join targets

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm going through the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins) and there's a part that confused me more than it helped me:

> What does Query select from if there’s multiple entities?
>
> The Query.join() method will typically join from the leftmost item in
>   the list of entities, when the ON clause is omitted, or if the ON
>   clause is a plain SQL expression. To control the first entity in the
>   list of JOINs, use the Query.select_from() method:
>
> `query = session.query(User, Address).select_from(Address).join(User)`

Is the "list of entities" the list within `query()`?

More to the point, when would the ON clause **not** be omitted?

By `ON clause` does it mean a relationship like `User.addresses` (previously defined for example as `User.addresses = relationship(Address)`) used like `join(User.addresses)`? Is that the type of "ON clause" that would prevent us from needing `select_from()` since the `join()` parameter itself would contain the necessary information for determining which table we intend to join with?

Surely there must be some way to specify join targets without having them always defaulting to the first table in `query()` since otherwise it wouldn't be possible to build certain complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the beginning. When you pass items to query(), it will build a SELECT statement from these items. If they are models, then it will enumerate all the fields of such models. The query will automatically add the tables to select FROM.

Unless you tell it to, the query will not perform joins automatically, so you must add assume what tables to look up your values from. Additional clauses like join() tell the query how the JOIN operation should be performed.

Additional arguments to join() will be used as the ON clause, otherwise the query will infer the clause based on mapper-defined relationships.

So to summarize, the ON clause is omitted whenever you do not specify additional arguments to join(). In the following expression, the ON clause is omitted: `query(User, Address).join(Address)` This does not mean that the SQL emitted will not have an ON clause; it will do the right thing by inferring the proper ON clause using the relationships defined on the model.

When there are multiple possibilities, you need to specify the clause yourself: `query(Person).join(Person.parent1).join(Person.parent2)` should result in a query that returns a person and both of their parents. In this case, the ON clause was not omitted.